# Call template when button is click

Tags: xslt

I have this template `<xsl:template name="calendarmonthview">`, how i can call this template by click at Month

```
<td colspan="1" class="tabletitle" height="21" align="center" width="5%">Month</td>
```

Comment: I think you're confused about the relationship between XSLT and the HTML it generates. The generated HTML has no idea about what XSLT generated it and cannot somehow magically invoke XSLT to generate more HTML.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use XSLT in a browser? Then call whatever [JavaScript function you use to do the transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) and set a parameter to call the proper named template.